# Dart catch clause

Tags: exception, try-catch, dart

I recently stumbled across the following Dart code:

```
void doSomething(String url, String method) {
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

    request.open(method, url);
    request.onLoad.listen((event) {
        if(request.status < 400) {
            try {
                String json = request.responseText;
            } catch(e) {
                print("Error!");
            }
        } else {
            print("Error! (400+)");
        }
    });

    request.setRequestHeader("Accept", ApplicationJSON);
}
```

I'm wondering what the `e` variable is in the catch clause:

```
catch(e) {
    ...
}
```

[Obviously its some sort of exception](http://news.dartlang.org/2012/08/new-exception-syntax-ready-to-use.html), but (1) why do we not need to specify its type, and (2) what could I add in there to specify its concrete type? For instance, how could I handle multiple types of possible exceptions in a similar way to `catchError(someHandler, test: (e) => e is SomeException)`?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

1. Dart is an optional typed language. So the type of `e` is not required.
2. you have to use the following syntax to catch only `SomeException` :

```
try {
  // ...
} on SomeException catch(e) {
 //Handle exception of type SomeException
} catch(e) {
 //Handle all other exceptions
}
```

See [`catch` section of *Dart: Up and Running*](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch02.html#ch02-exceptions-catch).

Finally `catch` can accept 2 parameters ( `catch(e, s)` ) where the second parameter is the [StackTrace](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/StackTrace.html).